# From cartesian to polar

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

How did my professor go from

$$\int_0^1 (1-x^2)^{\frac{3}{2}}dx$$

to

$$\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} (cos^2(\theta))^{\frac{3}{2}}\ cos(\theta)\ d\theta$$

Is it (somehow) from $x^2 + y^2 = 1$ and $cos^2(\theta) + sin^2(\theta) = 1$?

Comment: Do you know what polar coordinates are? This question is very hard to answer without knowing about what you currently know.

Comment: Please don't delete a question because it has been answered. People have given time and effort to provide you with an answer. It is disrespectful to delete their efforts in this way.

Answer (score 2):

Let $x=\sin\theta$, then $dx=\cos\theta d\theta$, and $1-x^{2}=1-\sin^{2}\theta=\cos^{2}\theta$. And when $x=1$, the corresponding $\theta$ is $\pi/2$ because $\sin(\pi/2)=1$.